# How to avoid infinite loop when two inputs update each other?

Tags: r, shiny

I am new both to shiny and to stackoverflow so please let me know if you need more information or if I should modify anything. I have an issue with the following code.

I want to have two inputs updating each other, one numerical and one select input. When the numerical input is modified, this should show the corresponding alphabet letter in the select input.

Converserly, when selecting a letter with the select input, the numerical input should show the index of the letter in the `alphabet` vector. The idea is that the user can easily cycle through the vector using the numerical input, and can select a specific letter with the select input. Ultimately, the alphabet will be replaced by elements of the periodic table and selecting an element will plot a graph of data associated to the selected element.

My problem is that, when a time consuming line of code (this will be the graph ploting) is executed in reaction to a change in, for instance, the numerical input, I enter in an infinite loop of updates between the numerical and select inputs (in the code, you need to uncomment the `runif()`line to initiate the problem on my computer).

I tried different things like setting higher priorities to the `observeEvent`, using `debounce` to execute the lengthy operation after the inputs are done updating each other. I also tried a solution that I found on this forum, using `renderUI` rather than `updateInput` but all these still ended in endless (or at least very long) loops for me.

```
library(shiny)

alphabet <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
      numericInput("numInput", "Numeric input", min = 1, max = 26, value = 1),
      selectInput("selInput", "Select input", choices = alphabet,
                  selected="a")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$numInput, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "selInput", selected = alphabet[input$numInput])
  })

  observeEvent(input$selInput, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "numInput", value = grep(input$selInput, alphabet))
  })

  observe({
    input$numInput
    #Uncomment the next line to create infinite loop
    #for (i in 1:10000) {runif(1000,0,1)}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Do you see a solution to keep the mutual update while avoiding the time consuming operation initiating the loop? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: R already defines `alphabet`, it’s called `letters`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

What about including a button, so that your time consuming code is only being run when the button is clicked?

```
library(shiny)

alphabet <- letters

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    numericInput("numInput", "Numeric input", min = 1, max = 26, value = 1),
    selectInput("selInput", "Select input", choices = alphabet,
                selected="a"),
    actionButton("do", "Run Your Code")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$numInput, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "selInput", selected = alphabet[input$numInput])
  })

  observeEvent(input$selInput, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "numInput", value = grep(input$selInput, alphabet))
  })

  observeEvent(input$do,{
    #Uncomment the next line to create infinite loop
    for (i in 1:100000) {runif(1000,0,1)}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks a lot for your reply! Unfortunately I'd like to keep the time consuming line to be run immediately as adding a button will add an action for the user. Cycling through the alphabet (the elements) will be done on a very regular basis and the "incrementing", "click button", actions... on 60 elements for many datasets will be less user friendly. I would prefer then having the numerical input automatically updating the select input, and a button to update the numerical input based on the selected element (this would be my backup solution at the moment).