# R shiny - Update multiple inputs

Tags: r, shiny

This is a fairly common question, I looked online for hours but cannot solve my problem.

I am currently trying to get out from infinite loops due to using `updateNumericInput` of three inputs (a change on any input should trigger updates on the other two). I thought that adding some delay via `debounce` or `throttle` would do, but I can't make it work. Below is the best I could do:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "num",
               label   = "Num:",
               value   = 10,
               min     = 1),
  uiOutput("num1"),
  uiOutput("num2")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  num <- reactive({ input$num }) %>% debounce(2000)
  
  output$num1 = renderUI({
    numericInput(inputId = "num1",
                 label   = "Num1:",
                 value   = num(),
                 min     = 1)
  })
  
  output$num2 = renderUI({
    numericInput(inputId = "num2",
                 label   = "Num2:",
                 value   = num(), 
                 min     = 1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$num1, {
    updateNumericInput(session, 'num', value = input$num1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$num2, {
    updateNumericInput(session, 'num', value = input$num2)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This works only partially: Updating `input$num` does delay updating `num1` and `num2` by 2 seconds. But, updating `input$num1` instantaneously updates `input$num`.

I tried to debounce both `observeEvent` calls, but that failed. From all I know, debounce only works on reactive values.

So I also tried to create reactive values `num1()` and `num2()` and use these in `observeEvent`. But strangely that led to changes in `num1` and `num2` not triggering an update of `num`.

How can I keep all three inputs in sync without entering an infamous infinite loop?

Comment: is there a reason why you use renderUI for num1 and num2?

Answer (score 0):

Would following code example work for your porpuse:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "num1",
               label   = "Num_1:",
               value   = 10,
               min     = 1),
  numericInput(inputId = "num2",
               label   = "Num_2:",
               value   = 10,
               min     = 1),
  numericInput(inputId = "num3",
               label   = "Num_3:",
               value   = 10,
               min     = 1),
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$num1, {
    value <- input$num1
    updateNumericInput(session, 'num2', value = value)
    updateNumericInput(session, 'num3', value = value)
  })
  observeEvent(input$num2, {
    value <- input$num2
    updateNumericInput(session, 'num1', value = value)
    updateNumericInput(session, 'num3', value = value)
  })
  observeEvent(input$num3, {
    value <- input$num3
    updateNumericInput(session, 'num1', value = value)
    updateNumericInput(session, 'num2', value = value)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: No, this works only in simple examples like this. In more complex apps that take a bit of time to perform all computations and re-render all plots, repeatedly changing one input before all other inputs update will lead to infinite loops (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57553693/how-to-avoid-infinite-loop-when-two-inputs-update-each-other) for example). I looked extensively for a solution, the best I found was to add an action button (I don't like it) or to delay (`debounce`, `throttle`, `delay`), but I don't know how.